# Some parameters are vulnerable to Command Injection while others are not. What can be the reason?

Tags: security, code-injection, commandinjection

I am solving the Portswigger lab for blind OS command injection. You can access the lab through [here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/os-command-injection/lab-blind-time-delays).

The feedback form which is vulnerable to injection has 4 query parameters; but only `email` seems to be vulnerable to injection. I am not able to comprehend as to why/how this would be the case in a real-world scenario.